# iText7 C# SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER) doesn't work

Tags: c#, itext7

I've been searching on websites and in forums and everywhere the code to hide borders in iText table is: .SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER)

It must be applied on the cells individually. Ok. But it throws me this error:

[image]

I don't understand why. Somebody help me?

Comment: You are probably referencing Border from another namespace. The correct namespace should be iText.Layout.Borders. Try iText.Layout.Borders.Border.NO_BORDER

Comment: Awesome! It works perflectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
celllogo.SetBorder(new SolidBorder(1f));
```